# coauthors_plus_edit_authors to display metabox based on author caps

Tags: plugins, metabox, user-roles, capabilities

Need to display the coauthorplus metabox with author capabilities.
On the documentation of the plugin they say its only with super admin and editor that the metabox is available.
Any idea to add a filter in the functions.php file?

```
function coauthorplus_cap(){
  if( current_user() ) == 'author' ){
  // what should I say?
  return true;
  }
}
add_filter ('coauthors_plus_edit_authors', 'coauthorplus_cap');
```

Thx for your help

Comment: You'll have to ask the plugin's support team about this. Third-party plugin support is [off topic](/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: ok, I will. Thx.